How can I retrieve the variation ID of the product displayed?
When we display a product with a variation, we have the id of the variation as a parameter in url like this :
/product/587?v=4951
587 = product id
4951 = product variation id

How to retrieve this variation id in a preprocess for example?
Currently, I do this, it works but I don't find this solution very clean
function custom_module_product_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  if ($route_name === 'entity.commerce_product.canonical') {
    $product = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('commerce_product');
    if ($product instanceof ProductInterface) {
      // TODO find a better approach to retrieve the variation id if possible, actually retrieve from url parameter
      $variation_id = \Drupal::request()->query->get('v');
      $variations = $product->getVariations($variation_id);
      foreach ($variations as $variation) {
        
        if ($variation->variation_id->value === $variation_id) {
         // custom code
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Is there another solution? I can retrieve product id like this for example : $product_id = $product->id()
